# Angular2 on Heroku ask for ssl while using symfony2 api

Tags: https, api

I launched a nodejs app on Heroku which is basically the front of a website in angular2. The app should receive the database information from an api powered by symfony3 hosted on OVH.

It seems that Heroku asks for "https", and OVH provide this service and is activated. But I still have the following error:

```
OPTIONS https://xxx/api/users/display_true net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE (on the console)
```

Someone has any idea to handle the problem? Should I buy a ssl ovh certificate?